# ¿Como trabajar correctamente con entidades que se relacionan en laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un modelo llamado `Inmueble`, sus atributos son:

1. Numero del Inmueble
2. Ubicación (en base de datos de llama `id_ubicacion`)
3. Tipo de Inmueble (en base de datos de llama `id_tipo_inmueble`)
4. Área
5. Descripción

Este modelo tiene su respectivo controlador (cabe aclarar que este controlador solo trae los métodos CRUD por defecto) y sus respectivas vistas.

Tambien tengo un modelo `Ubicacion`, cuyos atributos son:

1. Id (esta es autonumerica, por lo que no aparece en el modelo)
2. Nombre (el nombre de la ubicación)

También con su respectivo controlador y vista.

De igual forma con el modelo, controlador y vista para `TipoInmueble` (este modelo tiene los mismos atributos que Ubicacion)

El problema que tengo es que no se como relacionar los modelos correctamente, ya que, como mencione anteriormente, la ubicación y el tipo de inmueble son atributos del inmueble.

Habia leído algo sobre unos métodos `hasOne` y  `hasMany`, pero no supe como debían usarse, si son accesores o modificadores, en general, no tengo idea de donde y como usarlos, y no entendí la documentación que tiene laravel.

Adicional a esto, estoy haciendo el formulario de registro de `Inmueble` en laravel collective, y quiero hacer un select que me muestre las opciones disponibles en ubicación y en tipo de inmueble, como esa información es algo que viene de la base de datos, en el método que me muestra el formulario, estoy enviando también dichos datos en un array de la siguiente forma:

```
public function create() {
    $ubicaciones = Ubicacion::pluck('nombre', 'id');
    $tipoInmueble= TipoInmueble::pluck('nombre', 'id');
    return view('properties.create', compact('ubicaciones'), compact('tiposInmueble'));
}
```

Pero no estoy seguro de si sea la forma correcta de hacerlo, me refiero a la estructura que estoy usando, yo programo en Java, y generalmente no se hace así, por lo que quería preguntar si así se debería hacer, estoy usando 2 modelos que no le corresponden a mi controlador (Modelos `TipoInmueble` y `Ubicacion` cuando mi controlador es `ControladorInmueble`), no se si deba trabajarlo asi, o usar el controlador de cada modelo, o trabajarlo de otra forma, agradeceria si pudieran solucionar mis dudas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso de hasOne, belongsTo, hasMany o belongsToMany  depende de la forma en que se relacionen las tablas de tu base de datos.

Asumiendo que un inmueble puede tener solo una ubicación y solo un tipo de inmueble, la forma de relacionarlo sería así:

Modelo Inmueble.php:

```
class Inmueble extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'inmueble'; //nombre de la tabla en tu base de datos

    //Otras configuraciones, parámetros, etc



    // Esta es la relación con el modelo Ubicacion. Ojo que la función se puede llamar de cualquier forma
    public function Ubicacion()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Ubicacion','id_ubicacion');
    }

    // Esta es la relación con el modelo TipoInmueble
    public function TipoInmueble()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('TipoInmueble','id_tipo_inmueble');
    }
}
```

Si te fijas, se agregan esas dos funciones. La ventaja es que después tu puedes llamarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$todos_los_inmuebles = Inmueble::with("Ubicacion")->with("TipoInmueble")->get();
```

Esto te generará un Collection de Objetos de tipo Inmueble y cada uno contendrá dos Objetos: uno de tipo Ubicación y otro de tipo TipoInmueble.

Puedes buscar solo un inmueble con sus relaciones de la siguiente forma:

```
$un_inmueble = Inmueble::find($id_a_buscar)->with("Ubicacion")->with("TipoInmueble")->get();
```

Esto te retornará un Objeto de tipo Inmueble que contendrá dos Objetos: uno de tipo Ubicación y otro de tipo TipoInmueble.
Para acceder al objeto Ubicación de ese objeto Inmueble lo haríamos de esta forma:

```
$ubicacion_del_inmueble = $un_inmueble->Ubicacion;
```

Recuerda que en cualquier momento puedes transformar un objeto a array con ->toArray()

NOTA: En el modelo debes asegurarte de poner los namespaces. Yo puse solo los nombres, pero si, por ejemplo, tienes tus Modelos bajo el namespace APP, la relación tendría que ser:

```
public function getUbicacion()
{
     return $this->hasOne('App\Ubicacion','id_ubicacion');
}
```

Espero aportar

Comment: En cuanto a las buenas prácticas sugeridas por Taylor Otwell (creador de Laravel), es una muy mala idea usar un verbo al momento de definir la relación, no es semántico y puede confundir al leerlo. Por último y en caso que no lo conozca, el método with acepta arrays, por lo cual no es necesario llamarlo dos veces en este caso: `Inmueble::with(['ubicacion', 'tipoInmueble'])->get();`

Comment: Correcta observación. Lo de las buenas y malas prácticas son en realidad cosas de gustos y preferencias, que creo no aportan verdaderamente a solucionar un problema, aunque siempre es bueno tenerlas presente. En este caso agregué el verbo porque pensé que quedaría más claro lo que está haciendo, pero si tuviera que implementarlo lo haría como dices. Lo del with tienes razón, aunque lo puse separado porque no estaba seguro si el array está en todas las versiones de laravel. Me parece que se implementó en las últimas, pero en realidad no lo puedo asegurar. Buen aporte de todos modos :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, acabas de aclararme muchísimas cosas, de3 igual forma, gracias a @Shaz por las aclaraciones

Comment: @EduardoCornejo las buenas prácticas son vitales cuando uno recibe un proyecto que realizó otra persona anteriormente, cuando se desea retomar un proyecto posteriormente o cuando se trabaja en proyectos grandes con muchos otros programadores. No es asunto de gustos y preferencias. Seguir técnicas de diseño como SOLID o guías de estilo como PSR-2 no es un simple capricho, por dar un ejemplo.

Comment: @Shaz Te doy la razón. En realidad me haría un lío tratando de explicar lo que quise decir y creo que no vale la pena porque estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo. Que cada framework tenga sus propios conceptos de buenas o malas prácticas hace que a veces confundamos los menos relevantes (menos relevantes, pero que igual son importantes como tú dices)